# How do I install and test a Haskell package that I'm developing locally?

Tags: haskell, import, module, cabal, cabal-install

I'm developing a Haskell package and would like to test it as if it were an installed package. That is, I'd like to be able to install it among my other packages and then either `import` or `:m +`.

I can successfully build my package and (apparently) can successfully install it using

```
cabal install
```

which reports

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Exos-0.0.1.0...
Building Exos-0.0.1.0...
Installed Exos-0.0.1.0
```

but all attempts to import the package then fail with something like (e.g. in GHCi)

```
<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘Exos’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

even though I can see a populated `Exos-0.0.1.0` folder in my Haskell `lib` directory. (Even "uninstalling" fails with `ghc-pkg unregister`, which reports `ghc-pkg: cannot find package Exos-0.0.1.0`.)

How do I install and test a package that I'm developing locally, so that it behaves like part of my collection of installed Haskell packages — specifically so that I can import it (and "uninstall" it) like any other?

---

My package has the structure

```
Exos.cabal
Exos/
    Cryo/
        Exos.hs
        Exos/
            Display.hs
            Core.hs
```

with (relevant) contents in `Exos.cabal`

```
name:                   Exos
version:                0.0.1.0
build-type:             Simple
- ...

library
    exposed-modules:    Cryo.Exos,
                        Cryo.Exos.Display
    other-modules:      Cryo.Exos.Core
    -- other-extensions:
    build-depends:      base >=4.8,
                        containers >= 0.5.5.1,
                        split >= 0.2.2,
                        MissingH >= 1.3.0.1
    -- hs-source-dirs:
    default-language:   Haskell2010
```

in `Exos.hs`

```
module Cryo.Exos
    (
        f,
        g,
        otherFunc
    ) where

import Cryo.Exos.Core
-- ...
```

in `Core.hs`

```
module Cryo.Exos.Core where
-- ...
```

and in `Display.hs`

```
module Cryo.Exos.Display
    (
        showSomething,
        showSomethingElse
    ) where

import Data.Char
-- ...

import Cryo.Exos.Core
import Cryo.Exos
```

---

FWIW, inside my IDE, I can write an and successfully run "Application" with the following section in the above `.cabal` file

```
executable enigma-hs
    main-is:            Main.hs
    build-depends:      base >=4.8,
                        Exos
    hs-source-dirs:     tests
    default-language:   Haskell2010
```

and the following (relevant) code in `Exos/tests/Main.hs`

```
module Main where

import System.IO

import Cryo.Exos
import Cryo.Exos.Display

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStr $ showSomething
    putStr $ showSomethingElse
    -- ...
```

Comment: Use a Cabal sandbox and `cabal repl`.

Comment: @Jubobs: That's not the path I'm on. The question is how to get the import working "among my other packages".

Comment: @Jubobs: Man — I *see the answer* out of the corner of my eye: not `import Exos` but `import Cryo.Exos`! (Very embarrassing!) The other part of the question remains though, why won't `ghc-pkg unregister Exos-0.0.1.0` do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a simple one: If you look at the `Main.hs` example where you have successfully imported the module you have

```
import Cryos.Expos
```

and not

```
import Expos    -- wrong
```

that's because, the *module* you are importing is `Cryos.Expos` from the *package* `Expos`.